# Capturing email and password info

Tags: android

I have a screen which displays 3 editText for email address, password and password confirmation.   Pressing on the first editText brings up the soft keyboard which necessarily covers the other editTexts. Complete the email address entry and press next and a multiline entry box appears.   Complete the entry and press next and a multiline entry box appears. complete the entry - now a done button is shown but pressing it doesnt do anything.  I assume it should close the keyboard.

Questions:
Is there some way to indicate what the entry box is for when it appears?
How do I get the done button to work?
Is there a better way to capture email and password info?

Comment: "brings up the soft keyboard which necessarily covers the other editTexts." - I don't understand what you mean by this or why the user has to press "next". For your scenario, I simply put the `EditText`s into a `ScrollView` which means they can be scrolled into view even when the soft keyboard is open. The user simply has to scroll up/down and tap whichever one they want to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a OnClickListener to your button. This is usually done when you define your reference to the button. Here is a simple example:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

where `MyClickListener` is defined as:

```
private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do Action here
        }
}
```

If you want the button click to hide the soft-keyboard simply replace:

```
//Do Action here
```

With:

```
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasnt clear.  The done button is not in my layout - it seems to be produced as part of the softkeyboard functionality.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Check out this: http://savagelook.com/blog/android/android-quick-tip-edittext-with-done-button-that-closes-the-keyboard